# laravel - group data by DATE(created_at) with pagination

Tags: pagination, group-by, laravel, laravel-4

I want to show photos grouped by date. It works, but only with two queries and without pagination. Is there a way to do it with only one query, with laravels paginate() ?
I need the last 5 days (only those that have pictures), and then always 5 days per page.

The problem is, that i want to paginate the days,  not the pictures.

```
    $days = Pic::select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as datum'))
                   ->distinct()
                   ->orderBy('datum','desc')
                   ->take(5)
                   ->get();

$daysarray = array();
foreach($days as $day)
{
   $pics = Pic::where(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'),'=',$day->datum)
                    ->orderBy('id','desc')
                    ->get();

   $daysarray[$day->datum] = $pics;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you will have to live with two queries in order to paginate the dates. The following should work for that bit.

```
$days = Pic::select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as datum'))
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('datum','desc')
    ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: It gave me a wrong number of pages. (too many) I had to replace ->distinct() by groupBy('datum'). Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    $selectboxtwo = DB::table('downloads')
                    ->distinct('date')
                    ->groupBy('date')
                    ->lists('date');
                    dd($selectboxtwo); // making sure if it works. you can see the following array is produced.
```

array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "2014-03-09" [1]=> string(10) "2015-06-22" [2]=> string(10) "2015-06-23" }

Hope it helps.